# Проблема получения данных из SerialPort в службе C#

Tags: c#, службы

Цель - создать службу в windows которая считывает данные из COM порта обрабатывает и в данном случае будет писать в текстовый файл. Собственно проблема в следующем, не могу получить данные из SerialPort знаю точно что порт открыт,знаю точно что порт отправляет данные.
При попытке прочитать строку ReadLine() не получает ничего.

Как решить эту проблему?

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CanStop = true;
        this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        this.AutoLog = true;
    }
    comWatcher cWatch;
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        cWatch = new comWatcher();
        Thread watcher = new Thread(new ThreadStart(cWatch.Start));
        watcher.Start();

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        cWatch.Stop();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

    }
}
class comWatcher
{

    SerialPort port;
    bool enabled = true;
    public comWatcher()
    {
        Log("start");
        this.port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        this.port.DataReceived += port_DataReceived;
    }

    void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log(port.ReadLine());
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            this.port.Open();
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            Log(io.Message);
        }
        while (enabled)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        port.Close();
        enabled = false;

    }
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\\log.txt", message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы делаете неправильно.

Приход сообщения `DataReceived` означает лишь, что в порту появились данные, но не означает, что их набралось на целую строку. То, что в порт данные *записываются* построчно, вовсе не даёт гарантии, что они будут и приходить построчно тоже.

Если вы хотите вычитать все имеющиеся данные, имеет смысл использовать `port.ReadExisting()` вместо `ReadLine`.

Но более хорошей альтернативой мне кажется получение у порта `BaseStream` и работа с ним, как с потоком (не со строками, а с байтами):

```
class ComWatcher
{
    SerialPort port;
    bool enabled = true;
    CancellationTokenSource cts;
    public ComWatcher()
    {
        this.port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    }

    public async void Start()
    {
        if (cts != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already started");
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var ct = cts.Token;
        try
        {
            port.Open();
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            var stream = port.BaseStream;

            using (var outf = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\\log.txt"))
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var actuallyRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, ct);
                if (actuallyRead == 0) // end of stream
                    return;
                await outf.WriteAsync(buf, 0, actuallyRead);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                LogError(io.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        var cts = this.cts;
        this.cts = null;
        if (cts == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not started");
        port.Close();
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверное, cts надо пересоздавать в методе Start

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Угу, так и сделал.

Comment: у меня .net 4 там как я понял там из коробки нет async  но ваш ответ помог я просто сделал threed.sleep(10) и после прочитал  ReadExisting() спасибо.

Comment: @hamster278: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!